# Continuous scrolling up of open application window when pointer hoving over

Tags: drivers, touchpad

Odd but extremely frustrating bug!  When the pointer is over any open window the page scrolls all the way to the top.  If I want to remain at the current location of the page, application, or document, I need to move the pointer off to the side.  This occurs when using text editor, chrome, firefox, and terminal.

I have done some troubleshooting to following extent:  I have Windows 7 installed along side Ubuntu 12.04 and this issue does not occur within the Windows OS; I have turned off touchpad scrolling options, and I have utilized a mouse instead of the touchpad.  For these reasons I do not believe it is related to the arrow key but an issue with the pointer or touchpad driver possibly?

One other odd note is that when I start up there is usually no issue for at least a few minutes, sometimes as long as 30 minutes, other times immediately.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

TM